# Timezone conversion in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datetime, timezone

I am using ASP.NET MVC 4 for my web application and all database access is through WCF service. Now I want to display all the dates in my system in users timezone. The user timezone is saved in database and on login, I am saving it in the cookie. What I am doing is in Controller I am calling a utility method and converting all datetime to user's timezone. Is this the right way to do? Or should I call the utility method directly in the view? Please advice the best way to handle the situation.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Always store UTC dates in the database as you do not know who is going to view the items.

Before storing

```
var dbDate = myDate.ToUniversalTime();
```

And when viewing:

```
var userDate = dbDate.ToLocalTime();
```

Do remember to convert any dates to UTC before making SQL queries etc.

MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.touniversaltime.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Ideally, your utility method should return the time in user’s time zone (after passing it an argument that helps you determine the user’s time zone). You should then call your utility method either from a controller action or from the business layer (or from wherever you are populating your view model), then use the information in your view model to render your view.